# DRF dynamic filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, sql-injection

I need **dynamic filtering** in DRF that should allow using parenthesis for defining operations precedence and use any combination of the available fields in model.
Operations are: and, or, eq (equal), ne (not equal), gt (greater than), lt (less than)

example: "(date eq '2016-05-01') AND ((number_of_calories gt 20) OR (number_of_calories lt 10))"

How can I achieve this? what is best way?

Currently I have below solution but it's not good approach as it's vulnerable to **SQL Injection**:

utils.py

```
mappings = {
    ' eq ': ' = ',
    ' ne ': ' != ',
    ' gt ': ' > ',
    ' lt ': ' < ',
    ' gte ': ' >= ',
    ' lte ': ' <= ',
}

def convert_string(query: str) -> Optional[str]:
    if query and isinstance(query, str):
        pattern_drop = re.compile(r"drop\s+table\s*\w*")
        pattern_alter = re.compile(r"alter\s+table\s+\w+")
        pattern_delete = re.compile(r"delete\s+from\s+\w+")
        pattern_update = re.compile(r"update\s+\w+\s+set\s+\w+")
        pattern_insert = re.compile(r"insert\s+into\s+\w+")
        pattern_select = re.compile(r"select\s+\w+\s+from\s+")
        query_lower = query.lower()
        if '--' in query_lower or '/*' in query_lower or \
                pattern_drop.match(query_lower) or pattern_alter.match(query_lower) or \
                pattern_update.match(query_lower) or pattern_insert.match(query_lower) or \
                pattern_delete.match(query_lower) or pattern_select.match(query_lower):
            return None
        for expression, operation in mappings.items():
            query = query.replace(expression, operation)

    return query
```

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
    q_string = self.request.data['query']
    # q_string = "(date eq '2016-05-01') AND ((number_of_calories gt 20) OR (number_of_calories lt 10))"

    query = convert_string(q_string)
    # just replace 'eq' with '=', 'ne' with '!=', and so on ...
    # query = "(date = '2016-05-01') AND ((number_of_calories > 20) OR (number_of_calories < 10))"

    users = Users.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ' + query)
    return users
```

Comment: Can you not change the input? To some sort of DSL you write or well, to django queryset syntax? How is the q_string generated before reaching the backend?

Comment: q_string is request parameter, user sends it. Basically I can change the string, but the logic must not be changed afterwards. The example in question must get all data with date '2016-05-01' **and** (number_of_calories less than 10 **or**  number_of_calories greater than 20). It's completely free to choose which way to use DSL or django queryset

Comment: If possible then could you please share the details of `convert_string` this function?

Comment: consider django-filters?

Answer (score 1):

For parsing a query string like:

```py
string = "((num_of_pages gt 20) OR (num_of_pages lt 10)) AND (date gt '2016-05-01')"
```

you can use the pyparsing package (not an expert but very powerful library) with django Q objects:

1. parsing code:

```py
import pyparsing as pp
import operator as op

from django.db.models import Q

word = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_-*'")
operator = pp.oneOf('lt gt eq').setResultsName('operator')
number = pp.pyparsing_common.number()
quoted = pp.quotedString().setParseAction(pp.removeQuotes)
term = (word | number | quoted)

key = term.setResultsName('key')
value = term.setResultsName('value')

group = pp.Group(key + operator + value)

def q_item(item):
    """Helper for create django Q() object"""
    k = f'{item.key}__{item.operator}'
    v = item.value
    return Q(**{k: v})


class BaseBinary:

    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.args = tokens[0][0::2]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.symbol}):{self.args}'

    def evaluate(self):
        a = q_item(self.args[0]) if not isinstance(self.args[0], BaseBinary) else self.args[0].evaluate()
        b = q_item(self.args[1]) if not isinstance(self.args[1], BaseBinary) else self.args[1].evaluate()
        return self.op(a, b)


class BoolNotOp(BaseBinary):
    symbol = 'NOT'
    op = op.not_

    def __init__(self, tokens):
        super().__init__(tokens)
        self.args = tokens[0][1]

    def evaluate(self):
        a = q_item(self.args) if not isinstance(self.args, BaseBinary) else self.args.evaluate()
        return ~a


class BoolAndOp(BaseBinary):
    symbol = 'AND'
    op = op.and_


class BoolOrOp(BaseBinary):
    symbol = 'OR'
    op = op.or_


expr = pp.infixNotation(group,
                        [('NOT', 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, BoolNotOp),
                         ('AND', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, BoolAndOp),
                         ('OR', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, BoolOrOp)])
```

Now given a string like:

```py
string = "(date gt '2016-05-01') AND ((num_of_pages gt 20) OR (num_of_pages lt 10))"
```

to the parser:

```py
parser = expr.parseString(string)[0]
print(parser.evaluate())
```

give us our Q objects:

```py
(AND: ('date__gt', '2016-05-01'), (OR: ('num_of_pages__gt', 20), ('num_of_pages__lt', 10)))
```

ready to be filtered

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    num_of_pages = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    
qs = Book.objects.filter(parser.evaluate())
print(qs.query)
```

```sql
SELECT "core_book"."id", "core_book"."title", "core_book"."counter", "core_book"."date", "core_book"."num_of_pages" FROM "core_book" WHERE ("core_book"."date" > 2016-05-01 AND ("core_book"."num_of_pages" > 20 OR "core_book"."num_of_pages" < 10))
```

P.S not fully tested.

Comment: this is not working for single field, eg:- (date gt '2016-05-01')

Answer (score 0):

I currently use the Q object extensively in a project I have that is using the users get parameters to filter a search result.

Here is a snippet

```
some_initial_query_object = Model.objects.all()

qs_result_dates = []

qs_result_dates.append(
    Q(
        event_date__start_date_time__gte='2021-08-01',
        event_date__start_date_time__lt='2021-09-01' + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
      )
)

some_initial_query_object = some_initial_query_object.filter(qs_result_dates)
```

In your scenario you can use | for OR and & for AND

```
Q(date='2016-05-01')
&
Q(number_of_calories__gt=20, number_of_calories__lt=10)
```

Comment: The problem is that actually I don't know the structure query beforehand. Filter must be able to get any combination of the available fields in any operation precedence. Main problem is how to parse the user input into Q objects

Comment: How are you getting the users selections?  Is it through POST or GET or from the database?  It is definitely possible to parse any data into a Q object.

Comment: I'm getting it from POST request data like `q_string = self.request.data['query']`. And Client will send data in POST request like `{ "query": "(date eq '2016-05-01') AND ((number_of_calories gt 20) OR (number_of_calories lt 10))"}`

Comment: Can you refactor your code so that what is in the data['query'] object contains just a date string and just the number of calories?  `{"query":{date: "2016-05-01", cal_max:20, cal_min:10}` It doesn't seem appropriate that a query would be past through POST, GET, or from the database.  If you convert the dictionary that is coming from POST to the above, you can loop through the parameters and build Q objects.

Comment: This would be filtering based on only date and calory fields. But my question is **dynamic filtering**. User can send any combination of the available fields in any operation precedence. For example: `"(date eq '2016-05-01')"`, `(username eq 'test_user') AND (date gt '2016-05-01')`,  `(country eq 'USA') AND ((role eq 'regular_user') OR (username eq 'test_user') OR (date lt '2016-05-01'))`, and so on. ANY POSSIBLE COMBINATION IN ANY PRECEDENCE with AND, OR operators. It would be silly to write if else in every condition because number combinations grow exponentially as num of fields grow

Comment: Sharing with you the entire serve method using Q objects of one of my projects.  It's quite extensive, but you can see how you can combine any number of variables in any type of order.  https://onlinegdb.com/2pBzdhO26, also if you want to se how this code is executed you can visit the home page of this site and start filtering by clicking the dropdowns you see above the event list.  https://homecoming.berkeley.edu

Comment: thank you very much, but I can't force user to send me data in jsoned format. It's requirement to handle filtering with parenthesis and operators 'and', 'or'. Actual Requirement says: **The API filtering should allow using parenthesis for defining operations precedence and use any combination of the available fields. The supported operations should at least include or, and, eq (equals), ne (not equals), gt (greater than), lt (lower than).
Example -> (date eq '2016-05-01') AND ((number_of_calories gt 20) OR (number_of_calories lt 10))**

Comment: That is quite interesting.  I haven't seen items passed that forces you to use operators and such.  Which API is this?  I see you have DRF tagged, but I know DRF doesn't require that, at least from how I've built API's with it.

Comment: Yes agreed, however it's given me as a project requirement. And I choose DRF to implement the project, but it's completely up to me which technology to use

Comment: I agree that DRF is a good approach, especially since you are using Django.  I'm just not sure how I would personally approach this requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of dynamic filtering using DRF by overriding the `get_queryset` method on the `ModelViewSet` that I use in all of my projects. Using this method I can leverage the full power of Django-ORM framework from the frontend.

**views.py**

```py
def BaseAPIView(...):

    ''' base view for other views to inherit '''

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = self.queryset

        # get filter request from client:
        filter_string = self.request.query_params.get('filter')

        # apply filters if they are passed in:
        if filters: 
            filter_dictionary = json.loads(filter_string)
            queryset = queryset.filter(**filter_dictionary)

        return queryset
```

The request url will now look like, for example: `my_website.com/api/users?filter={"first_name":"John"}`

Which can be built like:

**script.js**

```js
// using ajax as an example:
var filter = JSON.stringify({
  "first_name" : "John"
});

$.ajax({
   "url" : "my_website.com/api/users?filter=" + filter,
   "type" : "GET",
   ...
});
```

**Some advantages:**

- no need to specify which fields can be filtered on each view class
- write it once, use it everywhere
- front end filtering looks exactly like django filtering
- can do the same with `exclude`

**Some disadvantages:**

- potential security risks if you want some fields to be non-filterable
- less intuitive front-end code to query a table

Overall, this approach has been far more useful for me than any packages out there.